# How to rewrite an register in binary file only if different?

Tags: c++, c, linux, raspberry-pi, binaryfiles

I need write a byte in binary file, but only if this is diferent (something looked like EEPROM.update(a) from Arduino IDE). I think there is some function that does this, but now I can't find it/I'm not sure that exists.

So far I have do this:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("file.dat", "r+");
fseek(fp, (long) address, SEEK_SET);
fread(&value, sizeof(uint8_t), 1, fp);

if (value == val) {
    fclose(fp);
    exit();
}

fseek(fp, (long) address, SEEK_SET);
fwrite(v, sizeof(uint8_t), 1, fp);
fclose(fp);
```

This code is an example, not the real code.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: There isn't one

Comment: You are not rewriting a register; you are modifying a byte in a binary file.

Comment: To avoid suprises with binary files consider opening in binary mode `"rb+"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fread` advances the file pointer, so your `fwrite` doesn't overwrite the byte at offset `address`, but rather the following byte.  You need to `fseek` back to offset `address` again before writing.

Also there is a `v` in your sample code which isn't defined.  Probably it should be `&val` or something like that.

Comment: It's true. I wrote the code on the fly to try to explain what I wanted to do, by way of example, so it's wrong anyway. My query was more about whether there is any function that allows you to do this in one step. Thanks.

Comment: @FAFernández: Okay, no, there is no single function for this.  You could streamline the process a bit by `mmap`ing the file, but still the read, test and write are fundamentally separate operations.